# CA1001 implement IDisposable on async method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, async-await, code-analysis

Consider following code:

```
public class Test
{
    public async Task Do()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);

        using (var disposable = new Disposable())
        {
            disposable.Do();
        }
    }
}

public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Do()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

When I run a code analysis in Visual studio I get a warning:

> Warning   CA1001  Implement IDisposable on Test.< Do>d__0 because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'Disposable'.

Why do I get this message? Disposable class is disposed correctly and I don't store it anywhere.

Furthermore this seems to be OK for analyzer:

```
public class Test
{
    public void Do()
    {
        using (var disposable = new Disposable())
        {
            disposable.Do();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably, a bug in the analyzer. The compiler transforms this to state-machine code where the disposable is hoisted into a closure class, exposing the variable as a field, which code analysis then warns on. It doesn't know the compiler-generated code takes care of disposing the object in any case, and the class isn't intended to be disposable by clients. Since a user obviously can't modify compiler-generated code in any case, the warning is pointless (even if the compiler-generated code should turn out to contain a bug!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's because compiler generates state machine from your async method, and that state machine class (named `<Do>d__0` in this case) contains field of type `Disposable` but does not itself implements `IDisposable` interface. It doesn't make much sense for analyzer to analyze compiler generated code (and this `<Do>d__0` class is marked with `CompilerGenerated` attribute). Fortunately, there is a setting for code analyzer to avoid compiler generated code: go to project properties, "Code Analysis" tab and check "Suppress results from generated code", and this warning will go away.

Comment: I have checked the setting and I still get the error any ideas why?

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the IL, you'll find that a class `<Do>d__0` is created to handle the async stuff:

```
// Nested Types
.class nested private auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit '<Do>d__0'
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    implements [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine
{
```

Later on, this class creates an instance of Disposable:

```
IL_0074: newobj instance void ConsoleApp1.Disposable::.ctor()
```

That's the class that triggers CA1001 because CA1001 checks the IL, and the generated class does not implement `IDisposable`. You can safely disregard the CA1001 warning on this particular class.